Como resolver este mensaje Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type ''. En windows forms
es un proyecto en windows forms entityframework core, me sale este error

Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type ''. The exception 'Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions`
el proyecto lo tengo estructurado;tres clases, inventario, producto y proveedor. dejo parte del código


tengo otra clase para configurar la clase proveedor

   public class ProveedorConfig : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Proveedores>
         {
             public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Proveedores> builder)
             {
                
                 builder.HasKey(p=>p.Id);
                 builder.Property(p => p.Name)
                     .IsRequired()
                     .HasMaxLength(50);
                 builder.Property(p=>p.Address)
                     .IsRequired()
                     .HasMaxLength(50);
                 builder.Property(p=>p.PhoneNumber)
                     .IsRequired()
                     .HasMaxLength(30);
                 builder.Property(p=>p.Email)
                     .IsRequired()
                     .HasMaxLength(50);
                              
             }
         }

   


aqui les dejo la clase DBContext

 public class AppDBContext : DbContext
        {
            public AppDBContext(DbContextOptions<AppDBContext> options):base(options) {
            
            }
        
         protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
            {
                base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
                 modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new InventarioConfig());
             modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new ProveedorConfig());
            }
        
         protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
         {
             base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
             if(!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured) {
                 optionsBuilder.UseMySql("miconexion", Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ServerVersion.Parse("10.9.2-mariadb"));
             }
         }
        
         public DbSet<Proveedores> Proveedores => Set<Proveedores>();
    
    **en la clase program tengo esto;**
    
   

 static void Main()
             {
                var services = new ServiceCollection();
             ConfigureServices(services);
            
            }
            
             private static void ConfigureServices(ServiceCollection services)
             {
                   services.AddDbContext<AppDBContext>();
               
                services.AddScoped<IServicioProveedores, ServicioProveedores>();
                
                servicioProvider=services.BuildServiceProvider();
            }
            }

no encuentro cual es mi error y gracias por la ayuda

investigando encontre la solucion era esta linea de codigo, referente a la conexion a la base de datos.. optionsBuilder.UseMySql(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["miconexion"].ConnectionString, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ServerVersion.Parse("10.9.2-mariadb"));
gracias
